# Proving $n^{2} > n + 1$ using Induction

Tags: induction

Suppose $$n^{2} = n + 1, n \geq 2$$

Prove using induction.

Inductionstart:
$$n_{0} = 2$$
Therefore 4 > 3 and the induction start holds.

Inductionstep:
$$(n + 1)^{2} = n + 2$$
$$n^{2} + 2n + 2 > n + 2$$

Question:

Is it okay to just drop the $n^{2}$ and compare
2n + 2 > n + 2 since this inequality clearly holds true.

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but looking forward to any help and explanations!

Comment: Your ideas are in the right direction, but if you want to formally prove this, make sure to explicitly say things like “assume the proposition is true for $n=k$; then I will show it is true for $n=k+1$.” Also, I think what you’ll end up comparing is $n^2+2n+1$ and $n+2$.

Comment: Thanks, I will write it more formally just wanted to see if it would be considered proved if I approached it in this way

Comment: Since $n>=2$, $n^2$ must be greater than or equal to $4$. You can assume $n^2>n+1$ then, so since $2n+2>1$ for $n>=2$, the inequality holds true.

Comment: This is definitely a more approachable and easy way to prove this inequality @MathAndPhysics, thank you! Nevertheless, the question demanded a prove by induction. Would it still be considered a prove by I induction if I used your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's better is to subtract $n+2$ from both sides to get $n^2+n>0$, which clearly holds.